# Sorting a List<string> with Times C#

Tags: c#, sorting, visual-studio-2012

I have a `List<string>` with Times as below:

```
8:00 AM 
8:15 AM
8:30 AM....
3:00 PM
3:15 PM....
11:45 PM
12:00 AM
```

Is there a way to sort this ? Something built in or do i have to write something custom for this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use List<T>.Sort Method (IComparer<T>), and write a comparer method, or try to parse the time to DateTime

Comment: The "...." is going to bring trouble in parsing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966.aspx):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {"8:00AM", "4:00AM", "2:00AM", "3:14PM"};
List<string> sortedList = list.OrderBy(s => DateTime.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Ah, I read `...` as "_the rest of DateTime string_". If it is literally `...`, then the key function has to be adjusted.

Comment: @AlexD: Understandable. And perhaps this is an answer to the question. But looking at the provided data there is more to be done... :)

Answer (score 0):

AlexD answer is correct, but using `ParseExact` with the actual pattern provided is far faster than `Parse`. Since logically, you're providing how to parse it, it is faster, also here is a blogpost tackling this, [DateTime parsing performance](http://blog.joachim.at/?p=42)

```
const string Pattern = "h:mm tt";

void Sort()
{
    var Times = new string[]
    {
        "8:00 AM",
        "8:15 AM",
        "8:30 AM",
        "3:00 PM",
        "3:15 PM",
        "11:45 PM",
        "12:00 AM"
    };

    var Dates = Times.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, Pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

or if you want the fastest parsing `TryParseExact`, you'd have to create a full delegate method instead of the simple lambda.

```
var Dates = Times.OrderBy(x =>
                {
                    DateTime date;
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(x, Pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
                    return date;
                });
```